# Openstack new instance error: "Profile is currently in use"

Tags: openstack

My Lab:

- 1 VM for MAAS 50GB HDD + 8GB RAM
- 1 VM for JUJU 50GB HDD + 8GB RAM
- 1 VM for LANDSCAPE 50GB HDD + 8GB RAM
- 4 VM for OPENSTACK 400GBx2 HDD + 16GB RAM

The services on nodes are all correctly installed, Openstack has been almost correctly deployed, but when try to create a new instance i receive the following issue

[image]
[image]

[here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/25222860/) is the log of /var/log/nova/nova-conductor.log on nova-cloud-controller. I've have reported also this 
[issue](https://github.com/openstack-charmers/openstack-bundles/issues/28) but I don't know if that issue is linked to this one

thank you for support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this solution three times on the same bundle of Openstack LXD, and I've resolved that issue:

After I've added the bundle of Openstack ([bundle](https://jujucharms.com/u/openstack-charmers/openstack-lxd/)) on Juju GUI I've first removed and then re-added the charm of LXD re-making the same its own configuration. Then I continued with the deploy of the bundle obtained this result:

[image]

For the problem on neutron-gateway I've opened a post [here](https://github.com/openstack-charmers/openstack-bundles/issues/28), but I'm waiting the solution.

At the end of all the procedure I've tried to create a new instance and the problem in all the three times is disappeared.

[image]

and

[image]

I don't know if the developers had fixed some bugs on this bundle, but making for three time the same procedure the creation of new instance worked fine without issue.